# GPU smallest compression is only supported on iOS 11.0 or later. Images.xcassets

Tags: ios, image, gpu, assets

[image]

[image]

Our team greatly improved the performance of our app by setting the compression of an asset catalog to GPU Smallest Size, however, we are getting this pesky warning.  How can I account for OS discrepancies in the asset catalog? I know I can use an if else statement programmatically, but how can I make the same operating system check for an asset catalog?

Comment: IMHO you have nothing to do here, on iOS 10 the OS won't have the GPU compression and that's all, if you want to just get rid of the warning that's another story.

Comment: This is part of an initiative to turn the warnings into errors. So we have to solve it. :( But otherwise @Mosbah, I agree with you.

Comment: There is an option to turn off all assets catalog warnings, don't know if that's acceptable for your needs.

Comment: That's a good consideration.  I'm considering it. I'll see if my team will go with it if nothing comes up.

Comment: hey @ScottyBlades what did you do in the end regarding those warnings? Did you ever have issues with iOS10 devices with optimized assets?